# Degree of Holomorphic Map between Complex Tori

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

In view of the classical theory, any holomorphic map $F: \mathbb{C}/L \to \mathbb{C}/M$ such that $F([0]_L)=[0]_M$ is induced by a linear map $G: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $z \mapsto \gamma z$, where $\gamma L \subseteq M$. Now, I have to compute the degree of $F$. So, I take $[z]_M$ and compute its inverse image $F^{-1}([z]_M)$. Clearly, it results that

$$
F^{-1}([z]_M)=\{[\gamma^{-1} (z+x_\lambda)]_L\}
$$

where $x_\lambda +\gamma L$ are the elements of $M/\gamma L$. So, I expect that $deg(F)=[M: \gamma L]$. Why is this number always finite? In fact, $\gamma L$ is a subgroup of $M$ and the latter is a free group on two generators. The subgroups of $M$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, for any $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. If I consider $n=1$ and $m=0$, then $[\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}: \mathbb{Z}]$ is not finite, am I right?

Comment: By "hits number", do you mean the degree or the preimage?

Comment: Algebraically, $L$ and $M$ are free abelian groups of rank $2$. Geometrically, if $P$ is a fundamental parallelogram of $L$, then $\gamma P$ contains only finitely many points of $M$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How to relate the geometry perspective, that is clear, with the index $[M:\gamma L]$? Does it suffice to say that the points $x_\lambda+\gamma L$ are exactly the points of $M$ belonging in $\gamma P$ ?

Comment: Each coset of $\gamma L$ in $M$ has exactly one representative in $\gamma P$.

Comment: Yes, $[\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} : \mathbb{Z}\times \{0\}] = \aleph_0$. But multiplication with $\gamma$ is an injective homomorphism, so $\gamma L$ is free abelian of rank $2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is an irreducible curve, then a morphism $f : X \to Y$ is constant or have finite fibers. Indeed, if a fiber is infinite, being closed it should be all $X$.

Comment: I'm referring to the index $[M:\gamma L]$ and not on the quantity $deg(F)$ for any holomorphic map between compact Riemann surfaces.